# Could not make proto path relative: java_out=C:\proto\: No such file or directory

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, proto

I'm learning gRPC and this is my first app.
I'm using windows 10, java Graalvm 11.
my proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package example;

option java_package = "ir.farshad.services";
option java_multiple_files = true;


service EmployeeService{
    rpc getEmployee (EmployeeRequest) returns (EmployeeeResponse);
}

message EmployeeRequest{
    int64 id = 1;
}

message EmployeeeResponse{
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    string designation = 3;
}
```

my run command

```
set PROTO_FOLDER_PATH=C:\proto\empoloyee
set PROTO_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\proto\protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.47.0-windows-x86_64.exe
set OUTPUT_DIR=C:\proto


protoc --proto_path=%PROTO_FOLDER_PATH% --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=%PROTO_PLUGIN_PATH% --grpc-java_out=%OUTPUT_DIR% java_out=%OUTPUT_DIR%  %PROTO_FOLDER_PATH%\employee.proto
```

and I get this Error

```
Could not make proto path relative: java_out=C:\proto\: No such file or directory
```

my folder tree is

```
C:\PROTO
│   protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.47.0-windows-x86_64.exe
│
└───empoloyee
        employee.proto
        run.bat
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet of the command, we see:

```
java_out=%OUTPUT_DIR%
```

It should be a flag:

```
--java_out=%OUTPUT_DIR%
```